# How to disable button until the user input is given and if it contains only 5 characters?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I want to get the following code modified..

```
<Modal.Body className="modalBody">
    Are you sure you want to unsubscribe?
    <Form>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        placeholder="Why do you want to unsubscribe?"
        name="unsubReason"

      />
    </Form>
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer className="modalFooter">
    <Button
      onClick={submitUnsubConnection}
      variant="warning"
      style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
      disabled={modalDisabled}
    >
      Yes
    </Button>
```

home.jsx .... This is the class component.

```
const validateModal = values => {
  const errors = {};
  const fieldVal = "unsubReason";
  console.log("fieldVal", values.fieldVal);
  //fieldVal.forEach(fieldVal => {
  if (values.fieldVal) {
    // || !/^[a-zA-Z]{5}$/i.test(values.fieldVal)
    this.setState({
      modalDisabled: false
    });
  }
  // });
  return errors;
};
```

How to get this done? I'm using this confirmation modal within a functional component and importing props from a class component.

Comment: You need a validation service.

Comment: you are reading fieldValue wrongly. it should be `values[fieldVal]` instead of `values.fieldVal`

Answer (score 0):

You can manage two state
 1. inputFocus : false,
 2. inputValue: ''

Now on input bar if user focus then setState inputValue: true And on also update inputValue and check if it's length is less than 5 or not. if more than inputFocus false.